# SVG <symbol> won't scale like the others

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having trouble with a particular icon not scaling.  If you go to [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I08p1isTJUXaTgeZ93sM?p=preview) you'll see the very first icon (the cup with the pencil, paint brush and ruler) doesn't respond to the space like every other svg element on the page.

I designed them all in Illustrator cc18 using `save` to generate the svg code.

For that particular icon Illustrator gives me this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="illustration_x5F_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 79 146" style="enable-background:new 0 0 79 146;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:none;}
</style>
<rect id="cup" x="0.6777539" y="67.352684" class="st0" width="77.6444931" height="77.647316"/>
<path id="ruler_x5F_shape" class="st0" d="M47.0672798,19.394165v45.8275757h1.1456909v-1.1456909h4.5957031v1.1456909h12.6415443
V19.394165H47.0672798z M48.2129707,22.8312378h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V22.8312378z M48.2129707,27.4140015h4.5957031
v1.1456909h-4.5957031V27.4140015z M48.2129707,31.9967651h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V31.9967651z M48.2129707,36.5795288
h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V36.5795288z M48.2129707,41.1622925h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V41.1622925z
 M48.2129707,45.7450562h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V45.7450562z M48.2129707,50.3278198h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031
V50.3278198z M48.2129707,54.9105835h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V54.9105835z M48.2129707,59.4932861h4.5957031v1.1456909
h-4.5957031V59.4932861z M57.404438,62.9303589h-9.1914673V61.784668h9.1914673V62.9303589z M57.404438,58.3475952h-9.1914673
v-1.1456909h9.1914673V58.3475952z M57.404438,53.7648926h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V53.7648926z M57.404438,49.1821289
h-9.1914673V48.036438h9.1914673V49.1821289z M57.404438,44.5993652h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V44.5993652z
 M57.404438,40.0166016h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V40.0166016z M57.404438,35.4338379h-9.1914673V34.288147h9.1914673
V35.4338379z M57.404438,30.8510742h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V30.8510742z M57.404438,26.2683105h-9.1914673v-1.1456909
h9.1914673V26.2683105z M57.404438,21.6855469h-9.1914673V20.539856h9.1914673V21.6855469z"/>
<g id="paint_x5F_brush">
    <polygon id="paint_x5F_brush_x5F_shaft" class="st0" points="41.6965485,65.2217407 42.4845047,31.4855003 39.8335533,20.8818035 
    34.5317612,20.8818035 31.8808079,31.4855003 32.668766,65.2217407    "/>
    <path id="paint_x5F_brush_x5F_tip" class="st0" d="M40.7088737,19.7361126
    c0.7722778-1.1733189,1.775631-3.1726189,1.775631-5.6534939c0-5.1422243-7.0509987-7.2129793-5.3018494-13.0826187
    c-0.7470016,0.8390205-5.3017902,7.9498148-5.3017902,13.0826187c0,2.8539448,0.819376,4.633482,1.5470791,5.6534939H40.7088737z"
    />
</g>
<g id="pencil">
    <rect id="pencil_x5F_shaft" x="13.5497589" y="38.286869" class="st0" width="13.7482862" height="26.9348717"/>
    <polygon id="pencil_x5F_tip" class="st0" points="22.6059189,25.2016068 18.2418861,25.2016068 13.7645836,37.1411209 
    27.0832214,37.1411209   "/>
    <polygon id="pencil_x5F_lead" class="st0" points="20.4239025,19.3829746 18.456768,24.6287041 22.391037,24.6287041   "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I then copy the code and place it in a `<symbol>` like this

```
<symbol viewbox="0 0 79 146" id="illustration_icon">
        <rect id="cup" x="0.6777539" y="67.352684" class="st0" width="77.6444931" height="77.647316"/>
        <path id="ruler_x5F_shape" class="st0" d="M47.0672798,19.394165v45.8275757h1.1456909v-1.1456909h4.5957031v1.1456909h12.6415443
            V19.394165H47.0672798z M48.2129707,22.8312378h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V22.8312378z M48.2129707,27.4140015h4.5957031
            v1.1456909h-4.5957031V27.4140015z M48.2129707,31.9967651h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V31.9967651z M48.2129707,36.5795288
            h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V36.5795288z M48.2129707,41.1622925h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V41.1622925z
             M48.2129707,45.7450562h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V45.7450562z M48.2129707,50.3278198h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031
            V50.3278198z M48.2129707,54.9105835h4.5957031v1.1456909h-4.5957031V54.9105835z M48.2129707,59.4932861h4.5957031v1.1456909
            h-4.5957031V59.4932861z M57.404438,62.9303589h-9.1914673V61.784668h9.1914673V62.9303589z M57.404438,58.3475952h-9.1914673
            v-1.1456909h9.1914673V58.3475952z M57.404438,53.7648926h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V53.7648926z M57.404438,49.1821289
            h-9.1914673V48.036438h9.1914673V49.1821289z M57.404438,44.5993652h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V44.5993652z
             M57.404438,40.0166016h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V40.0166016z M57.404438,35.4338379h-9.1914673V34.288147h9.1914673
            V35.4338379z M57.404438,30.8510742h-9.1914673v-1.1456909h9.1914673V30.8510742z M57.404438,26.2683105h-9.1914673v-1.1456909
            h9.1914673V26.2683105z M57.404438,21.6855469h-9.1914673V20.539856h9.1914673V21.6855469z"/>
        <g id="paint_x5F_brush">
            <polygon id="paint_x5F_brush_x5F_shaft" class="st0" points="41.6965485,65.2217407 42.4845047,31.4855003 39.8335533,20.8818035 
                34.5317612,20.8818035 31.8808079,31.4855003 32.668766,65.2217407    "/>
            <path id="paint_x5F_brush_x5F_tip" class="st0" d="M40.7088737,19.7361126
                c0.7722778-1.1733189,1.775631-3.1726189,1.775631-5.6534939c0-5.1422243-7.0509987-7.2129793-5.3018494-13.0826187
                c-0.7470016,0.8390205-5.3017902,7.9498148-5.3017902,13.0826187c0,2.8539448,0.819376,4.633482,1.5470791,5.6534939H40.7088737z"
                />
        </g>
        <g id="pencil">
            <rect id="pencil_x5F_shaft" x="13.5497589" y="38.286869" class="st0" width="13.7482862" height="26.9348717"/>
            <polygon id="pencil_x5F_tip" class="st0" points="22.6059189,25.2016068 18.2418861,25.2016068 13.7645836,37.1411209 
                27.0832214,37.1411209   "/>
            <polygon id="pencil_x5F_lead" class="st0" points="20.4239025,19.3829746 18.456768,24.6287041 22.391037,24.6287041   "/>
        </g>
    </symbol>
```

the way I'm using it in the `HTML` is the same for every icon which is like this

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; grid-auto-rows: 20vh;">

    <div style="grid-area:1/1/2/2;">
        <svg class="graphicA">
            <use xlink:href="assets/symbol_sprite.svg#illustration_icon" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div style="grid-area:1/2/2/3;">
        <svg class="graphicA">
            <use xlink:href="assets/symbol_sprite.svg#......" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div style="grid-area:1/3/2/4;">
        <svg class="graphicA">
            <use xlink:href="assets/symbol_sprite.svg#......" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <!-- etc. etc. -->

</div>
```

You can refer to the plunker for the full code.  Does anybody readily see what might be stopping this icon from scaling like the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the code, regarding `viewBox`.

```
<symbol viewbox="0 0 79 146" id="illustration_icon">
```

should be:

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 79 146" id="illustration_icon">
```

[Working version](https://plnkr.co/edit/A2WfZjGkOSQE02P3tbU8?p=preview)

Comment: really ??!! and i was checking path and other elements :) good catch!

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, I spent like 15 minutes scouring every *other* part of the code, attempting to spot some glaring difference. The solution was humbling, to say the least.

Comment: am not the OP :)

Comment: .....8......frikkin...... DAAAYS!!!!.... wow... thanks a lot.... *kicking self* lol